# Select value from dropdown from and taking another value from same collection from firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to get use a selected value from a field in firestore and use another field value to show in input from the same collection.

html file

```
<form [formGroup]="newForm">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="formProductLabel">Product Label</label>
   <select type="text" class="form-control" id="formProductLabel" formControlName="productLabel">
     <option [ngValue]="product" *ngFor="let product of product$ | async;">{{product.productLabel}}</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="formProductType">Product Type</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formProductType" value="{{newForm.controls['product'].value.productType}}">
 </div>
</form>
```

.ts file

`this.product$ = this.db.getCollection('products').pipe(); this.product$.subscribe((product: any) => console.log(product));`

When I run this, it says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')"

How do I go about solving this?

I tried `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="formProductType" value="{{newForm.controls['product']?.value.productType}}">` but it didn't show any value in the input field

Comment: Please share your ts code.

Comment: I do not have a ts code for this as I am not too sure how to. I found this solution but it doesnt appear to be working

Comment: this.product$ = this.db.getAllFromCollection('products').pipe();
    this.product$.subscribe((product: any) => console.log(product)); this is the ts i have to get the dropdown